# Outbuilding branched from LOAD side of GFCI

Tags: electrical, subpanel, shed

I’m usually not this guy, but I’d love to outline my plan and get opinions of what the red flags might be.

My treehouse is almost done.  It started as a primitive shelter, but is becoming more of a tiny house as I get further along.  And it’s time to upgrade from the undersized extension cord that is feeding the wiring.

Currently all power is 125’ away, coming from a “temporary” service pole with no main disconnect. It has four 20AMP circuits, two with GFCI receptacles on the panel and two GFCI receptacles in weather boxes coming out the bottom.

My buddy gave me some 6/2 AWG with ground UF wire that I hope to use that in the trench.  But I’m not ready to put in a sub-panel because I want to do it myself and—-there being no main disconnect on the panel—-I can’t see a safe way to do that without having the power company do a physical disconnect (which would mean permitting, and more attention to the treehouse, yada yada yada).

So my plan is to bury the 6/2 as well as another singular 6AWG UF (for the other hot) so that if my needs change and I can decide to put in the sub without digging anything up.

In the meantime I would connect just the 6/2 to the LOAD side of one of the external GFCI, giving me 20amps to use on the two receptacles I have wired in the treehouse.  It’s just for a mini fridge and toaster oven and to run my 12V DC lights through a power supply.  I would connect the ground to the GFCI as well as to the rod I pounded in at the base of the treehouse.

Obviously splicing 6AWG onto a GFCI load side is one odd challenge, and I’m wondering if this is the same or better or worse than just running a smaller gauge UF cable in the trench instead, or in addition to the #6 and just leaving the 6 buried but unconnected.

Regardless there will be a disconnect where the power enters the treehouse.

Anyway, hopefully that paints a picture.  Please tell me where I’m being stupid.

Thanks!

Comment: “ So my plan is to bury the 6/2 as well as another singular 6AWG UF (for the other hot)” You may not do that. All the conductors of a circuit must be together: either one cable, or individual wires in a conduit. No mix-and-match like you’re proposing.

Comment: Why don't you save that 6/2 and get some 6/3 instead?

Comment: This is great to know.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 ga copper would be quite adequate for a 20A feed if purchasing wire for the job. 12 ga would do for most purposes. 125 feet at 20a (or 16A continuous) is not that bad a run, particularly if you don't get hung up on the 3% guideline (not rule, unless Canada, I guess.) Given "the work of digging the trench" and the cost of conduit (once) for options to pull wire out and in if/when needs change, I will, as usual, advocate for conduit.

Bury the 6/2 UF if you want to "because it's free" and you're digging a trench (and junction box splice it to smaller conductors at the ends, a few feet of 10 or 12 ga won't bother the overall voltage drop at 20A) and put in empty conduit (or conduits) for "whatever comes next." Or fill the conduit to run more than one of your 4 circuits out there. You can change the splice connections to 6Ga if you ever up this to a larger feed, but that wire will (practically) be limited to 120V - just think of it as a 120V circuit only, or two if you have 250 feet of it to make a double run as completely separate circuits.

Don't try to put the UF in conduit - it requires a huge conduit and is not practical (nor easy to get into the conduit.) Use THWN in conduit.

Comment: Great advice.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a single 120V circuit, 6 AWG is wild overkill, but hey the price is right.

You cannot create 6/3 by tossing another single wire in the conduit with 6/2. It doesn't work that way.  You cannot use this cable to provision 55A **of 120/240V** to your tree house, but you know what?  It can deliver 55A of 120V (or about 45A if you want to keep voltage drop clamped down), and that's still a lot of power.

Attaching #6 wire to places much too small for it, *is a simple matter*.  You pigtail down to smaller wires.  For instance you get a MAC Block splice block or a jumbo sized wire nut to splice from #6 to as small as #12.  You can attach the #12 with no trouble.

Your outbuilding will need a disconnect switch.  You can accomplish that by using a main breaker panel, and it can be any size - the number on the main breaker does not matter since it's a disconnect switch.

Your burial depth for direct burial cable needs to be 24" *of cover*.  If the entire circuit is <=20A and GFCI protected, 12" is acceptable.  If you want to upgrade it in the future to 240V, then conduit may be a good idea - that allows 18" of cover. However 6/2 UF will require 1-1/2" conduit.  With individual wires you could get it done with 3/4" conduit.